# What is C++ abstract machine

Tags: c++, memory-model, abstract-machine

Well, I know Java has JVM and I've used C++ for 5 years and I don't think there is any C++ abstract machine. However, today I read this link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model and it said:

> Defines the semantics of computer memory storage for the purpose of the C++ abstract machine.

What does it mean by "the C++ abstract machine"? If it's not the JVM of C++, how should we understand it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is code stored and executed on the C++ abstract machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092889/how-is-code-stored-and-executed-on-the-c-abstract-machine)  I think it's just a concept the C++ standard writers use to talk about how C++ programs/compilers must behave.

Comment: TLDR : there is none. Everything is compiled to machine code which is executed directly.